# Transforming geometries for list of feature objects using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, coordinate-system

I am trying to export GeoJSON for a list of feature objects using OpenLayers 2. The features are in EPSG:3857 projection and I would like to convert all geometries to EPSG:4326. I am perfectly capable of doing this by looping through the features like so:

```
var construccionFeatures = layerCONSTRUCCION.features;
  for (var i = 0; i < construccionFeatures.length; i++) {
    construccionFeatures[i].geometry = construccionFeatures[i].geometry.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
  }
var json = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON().write(construccionFeatures);
```

I just would like to know whether there is a quicker solution. Is it possible to directly transform all geometries in the list in one go? Speed is key here since I run this process after a WFS layer loadend event in order to feed the GeoJSON to the [OSMBuildings](http://osmbuildings.org/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has resolved itself. I switched to OpenLayers 3 since asking. Data and feature projection can now be passed as options to the read and write function of the GeoJSON format class.